# Django model form with only view permission puts all fields on exclude

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Using a custom ModelForm in my default (django admin) change view gives me an empty variable `self.fields` if the form gets rendered for a user with only view permissions (new in Django 2.1).

This is my code:

```
# models.py

class Door(ValidateOnSaveMixin, models.Model):
    ...

    motor_type = models.ForeignKey(
        MotorType,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    ...
    door_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=DOOR_TYPES,
        null=True,
        default=None)
    ...
    vehicle_variant = models.ForeignKey(
        VehicleVariant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("vehicle_variant", "location", "motor_type")

    ...



# admin.py

@admin.register(Door)
class DoorAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    form = DoorAdminForm

    list_display = ('descriptor', 'get_customer_link', 'get_variant', 'location', 'get_motor_type_link',
                    'window_type', 'door_type', 'drum_diameter', 'dist_per_motor_rotation')
    fields = ('vehicle_variant', 'description', 'location', 'motor_type',
              'drum_diameter', 'window_type', 'door_type')

    ...

# forms.py

class DoorAdminForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Door
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'motor_type': DoorMotorTypeWidget,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DoorAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # this line is crashing on access with a user who has only the view permission, as self.fields is empty
        self.fields['vehicle_variant'].queryset = VehicleVariant.objects.all().prefetch_related('customer').order_by('customer__name', 'name')
```

The root cause is related to the exclude attribute of the Meta class in `DoorAdminForm`.
No matter what i write to the fields/exclude attributes, always all of the model's fields get automatically put to the exclude list and prevent `self.fields` to be populated. And this makes my code crash.

Of course i can check for `'verhicle_variant' in self.fields` but i don't understand the reason for that behaviour. I also couldn't find the part in the django source which populates the exclude attribute with all model fields.

Anybody has an idea if this is intended? Whats the root cause for that behaviour (ignoring the fields and exclude attribute of the Meta class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point where all fields get put into `exclude` is here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/cf79f92abee2ff5fd4fdcc1a124129a9773805b8/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L674

I have never used django admin with just 'view' permissions. Haven't really found a lot of information about how this should look like either: `django-admin` comes with add- and change-views amongst others, but no `viewonly-view`? Almost looks like it doesn't really know what to do with users that do not have 'change' permission. It directs them to the change_view and then notices that they are not allowed to change anything so it displays an empty form?
I suppose you could just declare all the fields as readonly for a viewonly-view?

---

UPDATE:
The field `vehicle_variant` won't be in `form.fields` as it would still be excluded due to not having change permission, but at least you don't crash on the form's init. I still have no idea what a change_view without change permissions should look like other than everything being readonly.

```
class DoorAdminForm(ModelForm):
    qs = VehicleVariant.objects.prefetch_related('customer').order_by('customer__name', 'name')
    model_field = Door._meta.get_field('vehicle_variant')

    vehicle_variant = model_field.formfield(queryset=qs)

    class Meta:
        model = Door
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'motor_type': DoorMotorTypeWidget,
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! Didn't spot it. I think they did a good job when implementing the R in CRUD :) So the viewonly view is actually the change view but doesn't allow changes, which makes sense to me. If i use the get_form method in the admin class i could omit the change argument and prevent the excludes. But i am currently not sure what side effects it will have. I will investigate.

Comment: Might just be easier to set the queryset of `vehicle_variant` in some other way. Explicitly declare the field on your `DoorAdminForm`?

Comment: How would you do this? I decided not not use the get_form method, but instead check for the keys in self. fields as in the view only view I actually don't need the query optimizations. But from the if statements it is still not obvious why I need to check for the keys. So I would like to have some self documenting way of implementation. But for now I am happy setting some comments on these lines.

Comment: Updated my post, I hope I am not missing something obvious.

Comment: I also used your suggestion of the update, and its working for ForeignKey relationships, but not for ManyToMany.